# CakePHP 2.4.5 - beforeSave() not being called

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, model

I have the following code in the User model:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!empty($this->data['User']['pass'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
            $this->data['User']['pass'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data['User']['pass']);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I am creating a new record through the UsersController by using:

```
$this->User->create();
$this->User->save(array('pass'=>'test'));
```

The record gets saved in the database and password doesn't get encrypted. Which means beforeSave is not being executed. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I ǘe got the same problem. Did you find out what was happening?

Comment: Yes... actually my model filename was incorrect :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the password or even the record gets saved in the first place because you are returning `false` in the `beforeSave()` callback.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
  if (!empty($this->data['User']['pass'])) {
     $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
     $this->data['User']['pass'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data['User']['pass']);
  }
  return true;
}
```

[Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave).

Comment: I know I am retuning false and that's what I am saying :) If the function was being called then the record wouldn't save at all.